# How to get the page/post template

Tags: wordpress, templates, post

I am trying to add custom divs into my index page and I created some page templates, that i was thinking of using as a way to filter out the pages. So basically if the post uses 'Media template' it would be displayed in that div.

But I am struggling in writing the proper php code that would loop trough all the posts and find the post that uses this template.

**In the end I want to find a post/page that uses  'Media template' and post it's content in the folowwing div:**

```
    <div class="home-media-content col-sm-3 px-1 pb-2">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

        <?php  

            $pages = get_pages(); 
            foreach ($pages as $page) {
                echo $page->post_title; //Posting just for the test
                echo $page->template; //SHOULD GET THE TEMPLATE and if the template name is 'Media template' display post content


            }
        ?>


        </div>
    </div>
```

I am not sure if it is the best way of displaying custom things so any better suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to use WP_Query**

See below for how I'd do it, using the `setup_postdata()` and `get_page_template()` functions. I think you should be able to get this info from the `'_wp_page_template'` meta for each page if you don't want to setup postdata, but if you're going to be doing a proper loop anyway then the latter is probably easiest.

```php
<div class="home-media-content col-sm-3 px-1 pb-2">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

        <?php

        $my_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type'   => 'page',
            )
        );


        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $my_query->the_post();

                  the_title(); // Posting just for the test

                if ( get_page_template() === 'media-template.php' ) { // This needs to be the file slug rather than template name
                      do_something();
                } else {
                        do_something_else();
                }
            }
        }

            wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset postdata back to normal

        ?>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. it even prints out not page titles anymore but something else. and i did find this function myself before [**get_page_template()**] but i couldn't make it work.

Comment: I've just edited my response, on reflection it's probably a more standardised approach to use a WP_Query instead, and filter by page. This should definitely output the titles of the pages as it's a really common loop structure.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot!